# How can I prepare yaml files to modify the SMTP/Emailing section in grafana?

Tags: docker-compose, ansible, grafana-alerts

I'm using `grafana/grafana:6.1.3` in combination with `prom/alertmanager:v0.16.2` (and some other in my opinion not relevant images).
 I configured the alertmanager to send e-mails via SMTP if a specific event occurs.
But there was nothing in my inbox, which is why I checked out the grafana docker log:

```
root@PRIVATE_INFORMATION:~# docker logs grafana | grep -n "alert"
162:t=2019-05-20T11:42:26+0000 lvl=info msg="Executing migration" logger=migrator id="create alert table v1"
[...]
197:t=2019-05-20T11:42:28+0000 lvl=info msg="Executing migration" logger=migrator id="Update alert annotations and set TEXT to empty"
292:t=2019-05-20T11:44:28+0000 lvl=info msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= method=GET path=/api/alerts/states-for-dashboard status=401 remote_addr=PRIVATE_INFORMATION time_ms=0 size=26 referer="PRIVATE_INFORMATION"
297:t=2019-05-20T11:48:01+0000 lvl=info msg="New state change" logger=alerting.resultHandler alertId=1 newState=ok prev state=unknown
298:t=2019-05-20T11:48:33+0000 lvl=info msg="Sending alert notification to" logger=alerting.notifier.email addresses=[PRIVATE@INFORMATION]
299:t=2019-05-20T11:48:33+0000 lvl=eror msg="Failed to send alert notification email" logger=alerting.notifier.email error="SMTP not configured, check your grafana.ini config file's [smtp] section."
300:t=2019-05-20T11:48:33+0000 lvl=eror msg="failed to send notification" logger=alerting.notifier uid= error="SMTP not configured, check your grafana.ini config file's [smtp] section."
[...]
```

I couldn't find any "grafana.ini", on my server. 
{ EDIT: I found two. One in "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/fe7[...]db3/diff/etc/grafana/grafana.ini", another in "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/079[...]26d/merged/etc/grafana/grafana.ini". Both contain the same information like the "sample-ini" }
Instead, I found a "default.ini" and a "sample.ini" file inside the running grafana container. The "default.ini" contained nothing related to SMTP, but "sample.ini" contained the following section:

```
#################################### SMTP / Emailing ##########################
[smtp]
;enabled = false
;host = localhost:25
;user =
# If the password contains # or ; you have to wrap it with trippel quotes. Ex """#password;"""
;password =
;cert_file =
;key_file =
;skip_verify = false
;from_address = admin@grafana.localhost
;from_name = Grafana
# EHLO identity in SMTP dialog (defaults to instance_name)
;ehlo_identity = dashboard.example.com

[emails]
;welcome_email_on_sign_up = false
```

Now, I guess, this is the place where I should have configured SMTP. Does anybody know, how to tell docker-compose.yml / ansible, that I want to configure this section during container set up?
I already defined the SMTP host and other information inside the alert container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approaches: the most common one is volume-mounting your already configured `.ini` file into the container, and the other is using environment variables of the form `GF_SMTP_HOST=whatever` as described by [the fine manual](https://grafana.com/docs/installation/configuration/#using-environment-variables)

Answer (score 4):

I have used below environment variables in my docker-compose and its working like charm!

```
grafana:
image: grafana/grafana    
environment:
  - 'GF_SMTP_ENABLED=true'
  - 'GF_SMTP_HOST=smtp.gmail.com:587'
  - 'GF_SMTP_USER=user1@gmail.com'
  - 'GF_SMTP_PASSWORD=mysamplePassword'
  - 'GF_SMTP_FROM_ADDRESS=user1@gmail.com'
```